# Rails acceptance tests - run Foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acceptance-testing, faye, foreman

My application runs properly using Faye, Redis, Resque and other services, that I am starting every time with Foreman. Now I am writing acceptance tests with Capybara+RSpec, and I wonder how I could start Foreman (or even Faye alone) with Capybara in `spec_helper` to test live features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to not depend on these services in your tests. I know [redis](https://rubygems.org/gems/mock_redis) and [resque](https://rubygems.org/gems/resque_spec) have "mock" counterparts that behave like these services without actually needing to run them.  Some services might not have a "mock" version (I can't find one for Faye), so you may just need to run them in the background.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I need to run only faye for now, but it need to be started with acceptance tests, not manually, is there option how to do this in spec_helper?

Comment: You can execute system commends from ruby using either backticks (\`start service\`) or `%x[start service]`. I would create a rake task that starts the service and then runs all your specs, and stops the service at the end.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `jenkins` as the CI server, you can start the `foreman` before `rspec` started.